# C/Linux - Scanning lines in a text file for a specific word

Tags: c, linux

So I am trying to figure out how to scan lines in a text document for a single word. The keyword comes from a text file and stored in a struct. The same file also contains a directory to scan for files in which to scan for that keyword. My program can read from the request file and open the specified directory. It also can see what files are in there. At this point, it errors out with a SegFault in the middle of trying to scan files and print back out to the user. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

/* Structs */
struct input
{
    char match[6];
    char path[100];
    char key[20];
};

/* Variables */
//char match[6];
//char path[100];
//char key[20];
int last = 0;
int linen = 1;
char filename[100];
char top[256];
int x = 0;
static int MAXLINESIZE = 1000;
static int MAXDIRNAME = 200;
static int MAXKEYWORD = 1000;

struct input insave[50];

/* Prototypes */
void readfile();
void readtdir();
void scanfile();

/* Methods */
//Scan directory in in.txt file for text files to scan
void readtdir()
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dirr;
    char temp[256];


    for(x = 0; x < last; x++)
    {
        dir = opendir(insave[x].path);
        strcpy(top, insave[x].path);
        printf("\nOpened: %s\n", insave[x].path);
        //printf("dir: %s\n", top);
        if(dir != NULL)
        {
            while((dirr = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
            {
                if(!(strcmp(dirr->d_name,"..")))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!(strcmp(dirr->d_name,".")))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("%s\n",dirr->d_name);

                        if(dirr->d_type == 8)
                        {
                            sprintf(temp, "%s", dirr->d_name);
                            printf("%s\n", temp);
                            strcpy(filename, temp);
                            scanfile(filename);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
    return;
}

//Scan lines of individual file for keyword
void scanfile(char *argv)
{
    FILE *fRead;
    char line[MAXLINESIZE];
    char templine[MAXLINESIZE];
    int y = x;

    fRead = fopen(argv, "r+");

    if(fRead == NULL)
    {
        printf("File cannot be opened");
    }
    else
    {
        while(fgets(line,MAXLINESIZE,fRead) != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(templine, line);
            if(strstr(templine,insave[y].key) != NULL)
            {
                printf("%s:%d:%s", filename, linen, line);
            }
            linen++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fRead);
}

//Read in.txt file for commands
void readfile(char *argv)
{
    FILE *pRead;
    int x = 0;
    char match[6];
    char path[100];
    char key[20];

    pRead = fopen(argv, "r+");

    if(pRead == NULL)
    {
        printf("File cannot be opened");
    }
    else
    {
        while(!feof(pRead))
        {
            if(fscanf(pRead, "%5s%99s%19s", match, path, key) != 3)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                strcpy(insave[x].match, match);
                strcpy(insave[x].path, path);
                strcpy(insave[x].key, key);
                x++;
                last = x;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(pRead);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = 0;
    argv[1] = "5";   //only used for testing purposes
    argv[2] = "in.txt";   //only used for testing purposes

    readfile(argv[2]);
    readtdir();

    printf("\n\n");
    for(x = 0; x < last; x++)
    {
        printf("This is: %s\n",insave[x].match);
        printf("This is: %s\n",insave[x].path);
        printf("This is: %s\n\n",insave[x].key);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let the debugger help you!

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

Instead of magic number 100

```
#include <limits.h>
// If NAME_MAX does not exist, try something like 1024 – 100 is small.
// At least during debug
char filename[NAME_MAX + 1];
```

Instead of magic number 256

```
// char temp[256];
struct dirent temp;
…
sprintf(temp.d_name, "%s", dirr->d_name);
printf("%s\n", temp.d_name);
strcpy(filename, temp.d_name);
```

There is no need for `char templine[MAXLINESIZE];`, just use `strstr(line,insave[y].key)`.

In `main()`, delete `while(!feof(pRead))`.  It serves no purpose.  EOF is not detected until *after* you try to read and get nothing, in which case your `fscanf()` will already have returned EOF and you will `break`.

Insure `0 <= x < 50` for `insave[x]`.

Instead of `if(dirr->d_type == 8)`, use `DT_REG`.

Do *not* do

```
argv[1] = "5";   //only used for testing purposes
argv[2] = "in.txt";
```

You do not know how big `argv` is.  Instead:

```
char *my_argv[4];
my_argv[0] = argv[0];
my_argv[1] = "5";   //only used for testing purposes
my_argv[2] = "in.txt";
my_argv[3] = NULL;
readfile(my_argv[2]);
```